# Pulling data sharepoint excel into ppt

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I will warn you: I am particularly bad with vba code in ppt and specifically one that goes into excel too.

However, I am trying to build a macro to automate a status report (items are stored in different excels, sheets, etc.). I already have a required template, so I would prefer to update tables (so the formatting does not get messed up- rather than add new). I'll write what I am trying to do with steps so that I can accurately communicate the steps I am trying to accomplish

i.e.

1. Open excel from SharePoint link
2. Go to sheet "Summary"
3. Filter on column G for value "open" and column B for "Action"
4. Store the rows excluding headers) for A, C, B, D, E (in that order for the ppt)
5. Go back to the PPT
6. For loop:

   ```
   For i = 1 To LastRow

   If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table 29").Table.Rows.Count < Array().Length Then
         ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(5).Table.Rows.Add
   Else
         'Update first column
         ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table 29").Table.Cell(i + 2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Array(1, i).Value
         'Update second column
         ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table 29").Table.Cell(i + 2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Array(2, i).Value
   Next i
   ```
7. Close Excel

Comment: can you just link the ppt to the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: No, I'm sending the ppt to someone and the excel is in a domain they don't have access to.

I'm also hoping to get some of the process on how to do it and use it in various other areas